# Ordering images in different divs

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to arrange images in different divs using something similar to display: flex and order? 
I want to make a grid 2 rows x 3 columns with an exact order of the images.

Actually, I tried Order with each image but with no results and I don’t know any other method!
Also, I’d want to use only HTML/CSS.

```html
<div class="section-c__container__column2">

  <div class="section-c__container__sub-column1">

    <div class="block-slack">

      <img src="img/logo-slack.png" alt="slack" class="slack">

      <div class="sub-block-slack">

        <h3 class="section-c__container__sub-heading">Slack</h3>
        <p class="section-c__container__sub-par">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque id varius eros, vel pharetra est.</p>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="block-gsuite">

      <img src="img/logo-gsuite.png" alt="gsuite" class="gsuite">

      <div class="sub-block-gsuite">

        <h3 class="section-c__container__sub-heading">GSuite</h3>
        <p class="section-c__container__sub-par">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque id varius eros, vel pharetra est.</p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="section-c__container__sub-column2">

    <div class="block-trello">

      <img src="img/logo-trello.png" alt="trello" class="trello">

      <div class="sub-block-trello">

        <h3 class="section-c__container__sub-heading">Trello</h3>
        <p class="section-c__container__sub-par">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque id varius eros, vel pharetra est.</p>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="block-asana">

      <img src="img/logo-asana.png" alt="asana" class="asana">

      <div class="sub-block-asana">

        <h3 class="section-c__container__sub-heading">Asana</h3>
        <p class="section-c__container__sub-par">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque id varius eros, vel pharetra est.</p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="section-c__container__sub-column3">

    <div class="block-salesforce">

      <img src="img/logo-salesforce.png" alt="salesforce" class="salesforce">

      <div class="sub-block-salesforce">

        <h3 class="section-c__container__sub-heading">Salesforce</h3>
        <p class="section-c__container__sub-par">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque id varius eros, vel pharetra est.</p>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="block-typeform">

      <img src="img/logo-typeform.png" alt="typeform" class="typeform">

      <div class="sub-block-typeform">

        <h3 class="section-c__container__sub-heading">Typeform</h3>
        <p class="section-c__container__sub-par section-c__container__final- 
    sub">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque id varius eros, vel pharetra est.</p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want to randomize the order of the 6 images?

Comment: How do you want to order them can you show the expected/describe order ?

Comment: I want to use flexbox to create a 2 rows x 3 columns grid. How to order the images in an exact order? The order is this from first to last following a row: slack, suite, trello,asana, salesforce, typeform.

Comment: since you're using flex maybe you can try `order`

Comment: I tried but since its's not a single div, it didn't work

Comment: People will be able to answer this question better if you include your wrapper element and also make it clear exactly what you want your final output to look like.  Even better if you can show something you've already tried, even if it totally doesn't work.

Comment: Is there a way to revert an edit? Someone edited and I approved for mistake, cancelling my code.

Comment: Yes, go to "edit" and click on the "rev" dropdown and select a previous revision.

Comment: I corrected the code, now this is the full html code.

Comment: Is JQuery UI sortable something that might fix it for you?

Comment: I want to use only css3 and html5

Comment: How exactly do you want them arranged?  Can't you just edit the html and arrange them how you want?  Is it being created dynamically?

Comment: Post a second HTML block with the way you want it to look.

Comment: I want this order, from first to last following a row: slack, suite, trello,asana, salesforce, typeform.

Comment: I don't know what you mean when you say "following a row".  Can you post the exact HTML of how you want it to look in the original question?

Comment: Here is the repo, I’m talking about the desktop version: https://github.com/CalogerN/1-fylo-landing-page-with-detailed-integrations-section The order I want is in the psd folder

Comment: So you want to recreate this look exactly using html and css?  https://imgur.com/a/1i61BfZ

Comment: yes and using flebox. Is it possible?

Comment: OK, that makes a lot more sense and now we have something to work with.

Comment: They usually call that look "cards", for instance: https://codepen.io/cssgirl/pen/NGKgrM

Comment: I see...I didn’t know it!

Comment: whipped something up really quickly, obviously you would have to fill in the content for each card.  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JgyKxG

Comment: @dmikester1 Thanks! Does it work with the current html?

Comment: Probably not, you're gonna have to change that.

Comment: I see..How do you judge my code?

Comment: How does it look?  It can be cleaned up a bit.  You have too many `div`s in my opinion.  Class names seem unnecessarily long.

Comment: I’m using BEM naming convention, there are some divs inherited from the mobile version. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yeah, that is fine.  You can keep the class names.  I've updated the code pen a bit more.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197366/discussion-on-question-by-calogero-napoli-ordering-images-in-different-divs).